# Acrobat is creating files starting with "magick-" What are these?

Tags: pdf, file-format, adobe-acrobat, imagemagick

I just noticed today that in every folder where I have PDFs, there are also a random number of files that begin with the word "magick-" which is followed by a string of around 17 numbers, letters and symbols.

I've opened these files with Sublime Text. They all seem to have an XML structure, and all start with "%PDF-" followed by a version number, such as "%PDF-1.5"

What are these files, and are they necessary?

Comment: These are PDF files.

Comment: OK, by adding the .pdf file extension I can see that they are indeed PDFs. But, why are they being created? 

I'm going to correct my initial statement that they appear in "every folder where I have PDFs." This is not the case - a disk-wide search shows that they're sprinkled across dozens and dozens of directories that have nothing to do with Acrobat, Adobe or PDFs whatsoever.

Comment: Temp files of some kind

Comment: Alright, well I guess I shouldn't worry about them. I'll just move them for now and see if anything happens...

Comment: Acrobat does not do that. You may have another utility (previewer? converter?) that does so.

Comment: @usr2564301 you might be correct. It seems to be MysticThumbs that's creating these files. I'm only thinking that because I found the app's temp directory filled with them.